# Datetime field won't change on UPDATE in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, mysqli

I've set up a database and this is one of the tables:

```
+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field                   | Type       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| id                      | char(23)   | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       | 
| claim_date              | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |       | 
| banned                  | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL                |       | 
| available_downloads     | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | 10                  |       | 
| last_download_attempt   | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL                |       | 
| last_activation_attempt | datetime   | NO   |     | NULL                |       | 
| download_exp_date       | timestamp  | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       | 
| available_activations   | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | 5                   |       | 
| os_version              | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL                |       | 
+-------------------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

The problem is: whenever I try to update a record with new values using both mysqli_stmt and mysqli->query() all values change apart from the datetime ones. 
The query I'm using is

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('UPDATE licences SET available_activations=available_activations-1, last_activation_attempt=? WHERE id=?');
$stmt->bind_param("ss", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $licence_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

available_activations value decreases, but last_activation_attempt won't budge. I tried even to hardcode the time value (both in "Y-m-d H-i-s" and timestamp format), I tried changing the data type to timestamp, but it's still dead. When I enter the same query in mysql console it works fine, but php doesn't seem to handle it. What can I do in this case?

**UPDATE**
What's the strangest thing - this piece of code is called as a class method from external application and when I call it (the method) from a custom php code it works fine (both available_activations and last_activation_attempt values are changed), but when I use this application only the available_activation value changes. It uses $_POST data.

Comment: In `bind_param("ss"...`, are you sure you want `"ss"` as first parameter?

Comment: Well, the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) states that available types are `i`, `d`, `s` or `b` - and you have `ss`.

Comment: Yes, if you pass the string as a date() you have to choose "s", if it's by timestamp, you use "i".

Comment: @Koyot: is there any error/warning? `echo $this->db->error; echo $this->db->get_warnings()->message;`

Comment: Ok, call me Captain Obvious, but could you please also check (`echo` or `error_log()`) for me the actual value/return value of `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")` and `$licence_id` in both situations (from your custom code and from the application)?

Comment: I'm really sorry to say that, but I'm pathetic. I was refering to old class while still editing the new one. That happens when one works under time pressure.

Case closed

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to recreate, I could get it to work. A couple of ideas: check for failure on prepare, bind_param and execute calls.

In this scenario, wouldn't it be easier to simply set the last_activation_attempt to NOW() in the prepared statement instead of binding in the date() value?

Comment: The query works definitely, as I mentioned before, because the available_downloads value goes down and datetime values still are "0000-00-00 00:00:00". Tried NOW() and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, but none of this worked as well.

Comment: If now() is failing, then your query is probably failing. Check that it isn't failing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much time as far as testing, but try using it in MySQL's timestamp format.

```
$stmt->bind_param("ss", date("YmdHis"), $licence_id);
```

I don't remember for sure, but I think MySQL prefers that way even though it outputs it in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format.

Comment: Nope, still gives me the finger